# How can I upload a windows installer on a custom pypi repository?

Tags: python, pypi

We're using a local pypi repository (powered by [djangopypi](https://github.com/benliles/djangopypi)) and I can't find a way to upload a windows installer to it. I downloaded a binary distribution of MySQL-python, which I want to make available so I can install it on a windows machine without the need for the full setup to compile it locally.

Is there a way to upload the package even though it hasn't been built on my machine?